# Google Vision API local upload not finding objects

Tags: python, google-api, google-vision

I have the exact same 1300x1000 image locally on my HD and in my google bucket. Using the code below, Google Vision finds two objects when I use the image in the bucket, and zero objects when I use the image on my HD. What am I missing?

Code for local upload:

```
from google.cloud import vision
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

local_image = cv2.imread(IMG_PATH,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

upload_image = base64.b64encode(local_image)
upload_image = vision.types.Image(content=upload_image)

obj_annot = client.object_localization(image = upload_image).localized_object_annotations

print('Number of objects found: {}'.format(len(obj_annot)))
```

This finds zero objects.

The google bucket code on the other hand, finds two objects.

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

bucket_image = {'source': {'image_uri': GS_PATH}}
obj_annot = client.object_localization(image = bucket_image).localized_object_annotations

print('Number of objects found: {}'.format(len(obj_annot)))
```

Comment: If those 2 images are identical, I would guess something is wrong with how you are sending the image inline from your local.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. It could be the conversion through base64, or it could be the request formatting. I've tried many ways, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Have you considered creating JSON and sending it? that way you can see the differences, and the byte[] of the image